# Where can I find the IBM SurePOS Protocol?

Tags: barcode-scanner, hid, pos, hidapi

I am working on a driver for scanners. I have a Honeywell, Datalogic, and Symbol scanner.

- Honeywell uses [HID POS](https://www.usb.org/sites/default/files/documents/pos1_02.pdf)
- DataLogic and Symbol use IBM SurePOS

I'm having a very hard time finding any information on the protocol. I have found bits on forms, like how to enable/disable the scanner. I also found this application [ShowHidCom](https://honeywellsps.my.salesforce.com/sfc/p/00000000SK3U/a/A00000000Grs/qqBL24sOaoFgV1U5oa1LaVBO41IUFT0PbmB7q_0B60w) that I can backwards engineer using wireshark USB PCAP.

I really want to know the IBM SurePOS protocol so my driver can be complete. I'm surprised this is so hard to find.

Comment: The IBM SurePOS protocol for barcode scanners is the specification for sending commands to the scanner, receiving responses, and notifying barcode data on the COM port. It's a de facto standard, but it doesn't seem to be documented like ESC/POS on receipt printers. However, unlike that, your question appears to be asking about the protocol between the scanner firmware and the USB serial COM port driver. It seems like closed information within a vendor that is not published anywhere. It is easier to get advice and answers if you clarify what you really want to know.

Comment: @kunif the goal is to know every possible command/response that could be sent/received between the computer and a handheld scanner using IBM SurePOS. There must be documentation somewhere. Maybe I reach out to Toshiba as they bought that technology.